# VB.NET MySQL query returns no value

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I am trying to display value in combobox using MySQL in vb.net. Right now the problem that I am facing is that combobox is not displaying values from MySQL. I have the below code:

```
MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=s974_db"

    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Label21.Text = "DB Connection Successful"

        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from s974_db.processors where Name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
            Label10.Text = READER.GetDouble("Price")

        End While


        MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()


    End Try
```

However, using the above code Combobox1.Text  returns nothing but if I use below code which has a different query it works:

```
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=s974_db"

    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Label21.Text = "DB Connection Successful"

        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from s974_db.processors"

        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
            Dim sName = READER.GetString("Name")
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(sName)
        End While


        MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()


    End Try
```

Could someone please check and let me know what could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Please learn how to use **prepared statements** in vb net, because every code is potentially vulnerable to **sql injetion** When your first code don't work, mysql tellys you that you have no data with that criteria. Test your query if they don't work in mysql workbench to see if they give any result also check the text of the combobox

Comment: First code sample seems to set a label text property only. Second code sample sets combobox items.

Comment: *`Query = "select * from s974_db.processors where Name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"`* - please show `Debug.Print Query`.

Comment: @nbk the combobox text is empty. However, I don't I can test that command in MySQL because it involves combobox which means it won't work.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer first code sample is supposed to at least populate the combobox at least that's the idea but it won't 

Second code sample works fine but I won't be able to achieve with it what I need. I am trying to fetch the name from the table and populate in combobox and then when a name is selected based on that it populates the label with the price.

Comment: first check if selectedindex is bigger than -1, so that you know something was selected, else you can't fill your label

Comment: First code sample only populates Label10.Text. Debug both methods and see what the query is returning in each one.

Comment: @nbk regardless of that let's assume label is not there shouldn't the query command fill the combobox1 with the values?

Comment: It is hard to tell without the full code, first fill the combobox usually during the load of the form. then the user has the possibility to select an item and then you have some possibility to run the second code for example after a button click or when the combobox index changed.

Comment: hey @AndrewMortimer i am not able to find the debug output of sql query command any idea where that would be shown in Visual Studio?

Comment: hey @nbk i can share the solution if you'd like to have a look at it?

Comment: no only if you got an error that needs afix. Programming is also writing a timetable, when program starts point a b c has to be rolled out, when user clicks on button d make so and so on. Your program is quite simple on form_load->fill the combobox ->on selectedindexchaged ->check if index is bigger than -1->fill label et voila finished

Comment: hey @nbk thanks but i am also quite a noob when it comes to programming. I have been piecing together this program by watching YouTube videos and couldn't really figure out why the sql command wouldn't return anything in the textbox. 

Would be great if you can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Post your code on pastebin and i will see what i can do.

Comment: hey @nbk the link is below:

https://pastebin.com/kQi6gr6q

Really appreciate all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the highlights as i mentioned them in the comments

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
' You need only to open aconnection once
MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=s974_db"

Try
  MySqlConn.Open()
  Label21.Text = "db connection successful"
  'First load both Combobox
  Dim query As String
  query = "select * from s974_db.processors"

  COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConn)
  READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
  While READER.Read
    Dim sname = READER.GetString("name")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(sname)
    ComboBox2.Items.Add(sname)
  End While



Catch ex As MySqlException
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally


End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
  Try
    MySqlConn.Close()
    MySqlConn.Dispose()
  Catch ex As Exception

  End Try
 End Sub
```

ANd now the Comboboxes

```vb
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
'Only when  there is a item selected , ask for data
If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
  Try

    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select * from s974_db.processors where Name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
      Label11.Text = READER.GetDouble("Price")

    End While



  Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
  Finally


  End Try
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
  Try

    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select * from s974_db.processors where Name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
      Label10.Text = READER.GetDouble("Price")

    End While



  Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
  Finally


  End Try
End If
End Sub
```

This is exactly as i described on Form_load you fill both comboboxes

When you now change one of the comboxes one of the label change too.

> Sometimes you have to update the Element to see a change

in that case you write at the end of the loop

```
Label10.Update()
```

Comment: You leave a connection flapping in the breeze until the Form is closed!?!

Comment: Hi @nbk you're awesome! Thank you so much for helping me out.

Now I understood the concept a little bit better and did solve one more small issue where Reader had to be closed because we were going to use it again in ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged Sub

Once again thank you so much. You're the best!

Comment: I added the language comment tag to the code sections to get rid of the red. It seems that if you add a comment in the code on a separate line, the editor considers the rest of the code to be a string. Argh!

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the top...
Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used. (Not Form level variables) You can make the connection string a class level string variable. This is the only way you can ensure that they are closed and disposed.

`Using...End Using` blocks will close and dispose your database objects even if there is an error. The constructor of the connection takes the connection string. Connections are precious objects. Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute` method and close it as soon as possible.

It doesn't make much sense that the user could select an item from `ComboBox1` before the `Form.Load`.

In general, we don't want to download anymore data than necessary and we want to hit the database as little as possible. In the `Form.Load` we bind the combobox to a data table that contains the name and price fields, setting the display and value members. Now, whenever the user picks a name in the combo we can retrieve the price without connecting to the database again.

I noticed that you were using `Val` in another event. This is an old VB6 method that can give you unexpected results. .Net and vb.net have all sorts of ways to get numbers out of strings that are faster and more reliable. `CInt`, `.TryParse`, `.Parse`, `CType`, `Convert.To` etc.

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private ConString As String = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=s974_db"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Fill combobox
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConString),
                cmd As New MySqlCommand("select Name, Price from processors;", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using 'Closes and disposes both connection and command
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Price"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
        Label10.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
        ClearLabels()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearLabels()
        Label11.Text = ""
        Label12.Text = ""
        Label13.Text = ""
        Label14.Text = ""
        Label15.Text = ""
        Label16.Text = ""
        Label17.Text = ""
        Label18.Text = ""
        Label19.Text = ""
        Label20.Text = ""
    End Sub

End Class
```